# Save screenshot from rtsp video

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am executing the following sh.

```
#!/bin/sh
export DATETIME=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
export DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
export MONT=`date +%Y%m`
mkdir -p /Users/User/Desktop/testFolder

ffmpeg -ss 2 -i rtsp://ip:554/user=myUser&password=myPassword&channel=2&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100 -y -f image2 -qscale 0 -frames 1 /Users/User/Desktop/testFolder/sample.jpeg
```

However, I get the following error:

> line 7: -y: command not found

And:

> [rtsp @ 0x7fd55980da00] method DESCRIBE failed: 451 ERROR
>   rtsp://ip:554/user=myUser: Server returned 4XX Client Error, but not one of 40{0,1,3,4}

What am I missing? I have ffmpeg installed with all options available.

Comment: you need to escape those ampersands in the URL...

Comment: @rogerdpack how do I escape the ampersands? Thanks in advance

Comment: try putting the url surrounded by quotes "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wan to wrap the correct @rogerdpack assumption in an answer, as I was stuck with the same problem and it helped.
You should specify the URL wrapped in quotes to get it work, as ffmpeg doesn't support switches for credentials specification and treats it as a invalid URL.
So just use like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i "rtsp://ip:554/user=myUser&password=myPassword&channel=2&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100" -y -f image2 -qscale 0 -frames 1 /Users/User/Desktop/testFolder/sample.jpeg
```